# How to maintain session on Amazon ec2 server? How to Prevent session creation for every request?

Tags: spring, session, jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2

I am facing very dramatic behavior caused by Amazon EC2 server. I have one web application deployed at Amazon ec2 server which is developed using Spring and Java. For every request new session is created here. I have one scenario where i need to store some data into httpsession object but due to session changing at every time I lost my data.

Your response is respectable.
Thanks.

Please add comment if forget something to mention here and its required to understand.

Let me explain my scenario completely:

I have two machines which have apache installed and integrated with tomcat server using mod_jk connector eg. app0 and app1 machines, this both machines are requested by load balancer of ec2 server. To replicate session for each instance of server i have used DeltaManager jdbc store setting because ec2 does not support SimpleTCPCluster setting.

DeltaManger code:

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"
      saveOnRestart="true"
      minIdleSwap="-1"
      maxIdleSwap="-1"
      maxIdleBackup="20"
      processExpiresFrequency="1">
      <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore"
        connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tomcat"
        driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        connectionName="username"
        connectionPassword="password"
        sessionIdCol="session_id"
        sessionValidCol="valid_session"
        sessionMaxInactiveCol="max_inactive"
        sessionLastAccessedCol="last_access"
        sessionTable="sessions"
        sessionAppCol="app_name"
        sessionDataCol="session_data"
      />
    </Manager>
```

This all works fine on my local machine but failed on production as there are two machines and they are handled by ec2 load balancer.

Please comment if any thing else required.

Comment: This should not have anything to do with EC2 instance. How exactly do you create sessions? Do you use spring rest? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for your quickr reply.
request.getSession().setAttribute("name", "name");
This is the way i am setting value in session. I am not using spring rest, my code is written using Spring framework Controller which accepts client request and rendered page according to that request. If I will print session id on jsp it is changing on refresh also.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I've created a very simple Hello World application which displays session ID in a JSP.  I can't get JDBC store to actually persist the sessions, and it isn't providing any useful logging

Comment: This is the exact issue I am facing right now. Local machine it's working fine but exactly same code breaks session in the aws linux.May I know how did you fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with session was that jsessionid cookie was removed from the request due to the different path. App has a "/" (root) as a path and jsessionid had a path "/". This was causing jsessionid to be removed from the request and since server never received the jsessionid it was creating the new one all the time.
We fixed the issue by adding parameter - emptySessionPath="true" - to all connectors in /etc/tomcat6/server.xml.